# What's the name of this style of scrollbar?

Tags: c#, .net, scrollbar, richtextbox

Does this style of scrollbar have a name? I'm trying to debug why my richtextbox will display a smooth bar versus this one with 3 lines on it. I'm guessing it has something to do with Word Wrap?

[image]
**Power Responders:** I know it's a vertical scrollbar, I just want to know the name of scrollbar that has 3 lines on it vs the normal one.

Comment: Three-lines-scrollbar lol

Comment: I've noticed that the 3-bar icon disappears if the slider thumb is getting too short.

Comment: Windows has a nice GUI (right click on things brings up a menu); I was wondering what the "hamburger" signified

Comment: You need an old version of Windows to see it, Win7 was the last one I think.  It is just a plain scrollbar, the lines show up because the thumb is so large.